# As nouns, dispute vs. disputation

Tags: difference

I colored "disputation" below in gray. 1. Would it be correct to substitute it with "dispute", which is both a verb and noun?

2. In general, how does 'dispute' differ from 'disputation' AS NOUNS? I know that disputation isn't a verb.

> **Coherence, clarity, and readability.** Do the included facts give coherence or clarity to the story? Do they help create a readable text? Once mentioned, facts can be repeated to lead readers from one sentence or paragraph to another. For example, in Table 33, sentence 3 begins with the useful transition *shortly after his reinstatement*, which repeats information from sentence 2, namely that Hazelwood was *reinstated*. For another example, sentence 6 repeats the fact that Exxon knew the captain was an alcoholic, in the phrasing *Exxon’s known alcoholic captain*. Repeated information is not always problematic (see Strategy 30 and Strategy 4); it can be useful in providing transitions. However, if not useful, you should consider omitting the information.
>        If you are unsure of the `disputation` of a certain fact, that does not necessarily affect whether or not you retain the fact. The facts you retain still need to be relevant to the law, and they need to help clarify the story or help it cohere or assist in the readability of the text. If they do not achieve these purposes, you can omit them.

Sandra Oster [MA (Portland State University), PhD (University of Michigan) JD (Northwestern School of Law, Lewis and Clark College)](https://nunm.edu/faculty/sandra-oster-jd-phd/), *Writing Shorter Legal Documents* (2011), p 165.

[image]

*Op. cit.* p 167.

Comment: On this site, images of text relevant to the question aren't allowed. Please type all the text you would like to include and remove the image from your question

Comment: Generally, the *-ation* form means the *act* or *process* of, please see [What's the difference between disputation and dispute?](https://comparewords.com/disputation/dispute)

Comment: @gotube I don't know how to format indents here.

Comment: @Coosf type the content of the image into the body or copy-paste it from the source, if you have access to it. Someone else will likely format it for you, maybe me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the word "disputation" looks odd.  However, I take it to be a legal term with a precise meaning for lawyers. The sense of "disputation" seems to be "the process of establishing a point of law or a fact by disputes between lawyers before a court".

As a technical term, you can't change it to "dispute". Technical terms are used with careful and exact meanings.

Being "unsure of the disputation" means you are not certain of how the fact was ascertained.  Being "unsure of the dispute" is probably not legally idiomatic.